# Pasar datos de un gridview(de asp.net) a textbox(asp.net) de ventana modal boostrap

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap

mi problema consiste en que no encuentro la forma para pasar los datos que tengo en un gridview a un textbox que tengo dentro de una ventana modal de boostrap, creo que mi problema radica en que de alguna forma si puedo mandar los datos al textbox por medio de un boton pero este mismo boton no puede abrir la ventana modal ya que es un objeto de tipo asp:CommandField y en este no puedo meter el data-target que es la propiedad que se necesita para poder abrir la ventana modal.

este es el codigo asp del objeto con el que mando el valor al textbox

```
  <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bitacora">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <!-- Este es el botón con el que abro mi ventana modal -->
                <button type='button' class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalMiniborar">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" >
                </span> 
            prueba</button>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" /> <!-- Este es el objeto con el que mando el dato a mi textbox -->
   </Columns>
```

lo que yo quiero saber si hay alguna manera de poder enviar los datos y abrir la ventana modal al mismo tiempo.

Comment: puedes abrir el modal pero no visualizar la data?

Comment: si puedo visualizar el dato en la modal , lo que pasa es que para poder hacer lo que quiero tengo que primero presionar un botón para poder enviar el dato y después presionar el otro botón para abrir la modal , lo que quiero hacer es que con un solo botón se carguen los datos y se abra la modal

Answer (score -1):

Quizás es más sencillo de lo que intentas realizar. Mediante javascript puedes conseguirlo.

Una modal de Bootstrap no es más que un elemento `<div/>` de html con unos estilos para resaltarla sobre los demás elementos html de la página.

Una gridView de asp.net renderiza una tabla de html `<table/>`. 
Simplemente al abrir la modal puedes enlazar algún evento javascript, que lea el valor de la celda html y lo establezca en el textbox de tu modal (que se renderiza como un elemento `<input/>` de html).

Todos esos elementos pertenecen al mismo DOM y puedes acceder a ellos sin problemas.